# force ADB to accept connections to all local IPs

Tags: android, networking, tcp

I am running an android device in an emulator. Android device is hosting a TCP  server. I have setup port forwarding using `adb forward tcp:local_port tcp:remote_port` on my dev computer. To test it, I try to connect to the device using telnet: `telnet localhost local_port` and it works fine. On the other hand, if I try to connect to my emulator using my IP address instead of the localhost - connection fails. To me it seems that the adb binds only to the localhost instead of 0.0.0.0. Is there a way to force the adb to bind to all local addresses, instead of just localhost?